# How to align images and urls within div trees in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am learning how to become Front End Developer at Udacity. There is a project that I need to submit. I ran in couple of issues I couldn't find help with, some of my images and urls within divs don't want to align properly. I tried using this website as a solution https://codemyviews.com/blog/how-to-center-anything-with-css
because it offered most variations on aligning blocks... But none of them worked.

```
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4"><img src="http://www.panext.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/question-63916_640-400x200.jpg"></div>
        <div class="col-4"><img src="http://www.eu-projekti.info/eu/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/1159613_85120857-400x200.jpg"></div>
        <div class="col-4 end"><img src="http://www.digitalzenway.com/wp-content/uploads/plan-to-eat-400x200.gif"></div>
    </div>
```

These are images, I am trying to align first image to the left, 2nd to the center and 3rd to the right. I could align them by using margins and paddings in html, but I want it to work with responsive design.

```
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <a href="https://github.com/udacity/Appify/">https://github.com/udacity/Appify/</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <a href="https://github.com/udacity/Sunflower/">https://github.com/udacity/Sunflower/</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <a href="https://github.com/udacity/Bokeh">https://github.com/udacity/Bokeh/</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and these are urls right underneath the pictures, that aren't lining up, no matter what I try.

This is the screenshot of my webpage http://picpaste.com/Portfolio-NOGcuGm8.jpg

P.S. This is my first post at Stack Overflow, TIA!

Comment: This came to my mind on aligning images. For some reason text-align: center does not work when you target images directly, so I nested my images inside <p> tags and applied text-align: center to <p> tags and the magic worked. Although I think there is a better solution for it

Comment: The reason this worked is because `p` tags are (by default) block-level elements, which means they span the width of their containers.  By specifying `text-align: center`, you centered everything within that full width.  You can avoid using another tag by applying the style directly to the container outside the `img`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap's `text-center` and `text-right` classes to modify inner alignment of columns.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4"><img src="http://www.panext.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/question-63916_640-400x200.jpg"></div>
    <div class="col-4 text-center"><img src="http://www.eu-projekti.info/eu/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/1159613_85120857-400x200.jpg"></div>
    <div class="col-4 text-right end"><img src="http://www.digitalzenway.com/wp-content/uploads/plan-to-eat-400x200.gif"></div>
</div>
```

If you aren't using Bootstrap, these classes simply apply `text-align: center` and `text-align: right` respectively.

Comment: .col-4 img { text-align: right; }

This doesn't work in my case for some reason. I know I am targeting right images, because changing margins does move them.

Comment: [link] (http://picpaste.com/protfoli_urls-VA1r0i4D.jpg)

Even though I am assigning 4 colums per url * 3 = 12 columns. You can see on this picture how borders end right where url ends... Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yeah - you can't align the image itself, you set the `text-align` property on the container - in this case, the col-4.  There unfortunately isn't a selector for all col-4s with images, so you'll have to use `text-center` as in my post or inline-style it.